# using getBoundingClientRect, getBBox in a svg string?

Tags: jquery, svg

Hi I have the next svg string str=

```
<svg width="612" height="394" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <g>
     <title>Layer 1</title>
     <rect id="svg_1" height="152" width="265" y="44" x="91" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
 <g>
     <title>Layer 2</title>
     <rect id="svg_2" height="125" width="151" y="157" x="399" stroke-width="5" stroke="#000000" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

In order to get the width and height of the first rectangle I can use javascript+jquery:

```
alert("width:"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)').attr('width'));
alert("height:"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)').attr('height'));
```

I would like to find the same usign either .getBoundingClientRect() or .getBBox()
I have tried:

```
alert("height"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)').getBoundingClientRect().width);
alert("height"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)').getBBox().width);
```

but it doesn't work. Anyone knows a solution? how can I do to use getBoundingClientRect and getBBox and my string str? thanks

Answer (score 5):

jQuery returns a jQuery object, you need the actual DOM element. To this you can simply add `[0]` after your selector:

```
alert("height"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)')[0].getBoundingClientRect().width);
alert("height"+$(str).find('g:eq(0) rect:eq(0)')[0].getBBox().width);
```

Note that to get dimensions the element must be added to the DOM, it should not be simply a string.

Also, a faster and more elegant way to do this would be...

```
//no need to indicate the first element since querySelector already does this;
var el = str.querySelector('g rect');
alert( "width: " + el.getBoundingClientRect().width );
alert( "width: " + el.getBBox().width );
```

Comment: Hi, If I use: $('#idtest').html(str);
var Box=document.getElementById('svg_1').getBBox();                       and <div id="idtest" class="sli" style="visibility:hidden" ></div>   it works. But I don't know how to add str to the DOM in order to use your last advices....